# create own modal in angularjs, bootstrap no

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

in my last design, i create my own template without bootstrap.
and i inject my code with angularjs.

So here's my case:
i want to show my data form in editing template and i need modal to show

there's a way to build my own modal directive?

i have my code like this:

```
angular.directive('myModal', function() {
    var template = '<div class="modal" ng-show="viewModal">modal here!<a ng-click="close()">Close</a></div><a ng-show="showModal" ng-hide="viewModal" ng-click="view()">Click me</a>';
    return {
        scope: {
            title: '=',
            template: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.view = function() {
                scope.viewModal = true;
            }
            scope.close = function() {
                scope.viewModal = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

thanks for the answer

Comment: You might want to look into transclusion, so you can define your modal content's markup outside of your modal directive. This is a good [video tutorial on egghead.io](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-transclusion-basics)

Comment: thanks for that, :) but how modal content inject with other template like form.html?

Comment: and how to create modal hide and show?

Comment: If you add `<div data-my-modal>Hello world!</div>` inside the template/partial of another directive (ie. `form.html`) you can use [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) to parse your `form.html`. That will instantiate any angular directives (ie. my-modal) hiding inside your `form.html` markup.

Comment: thanks again to you Phil, may be you can write me your code?

Comment: coz i still don't understand about how to put the $compile, in link or compile? please help